# How to get a valid answer when asking for a number or a letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main ():
    input('press enter to begin testing...')

    counter = 0
    total = 0;

    value = int( input ("Enter temp:  or q to quit " ))

    maxval = value
    minval = value

    while value:
        counter += 1
        total += value

        if value > maxval:
            maxval = value
        if value < minval:
            minval = value

        value = int( input ("Enter temp:  or q to quit "))

    print ( 'Total is:  ', total)
    print ('Counter is: ', counter)

    if counter != 0:
        print ('Average is: ', total / counter)
        print ('Minimum is:  ', minval)
        print ('Maximum is:   ', maxval)
```

The problem is when asking for a `temp` or `q` to quit since it is an int `q` is not accepted since it is a str.

I tried asking separate questions but then it doesnt correctly count the loops. Then I tried `ord ('q')` which is `113`. I'm not sure how to get this to apply successfully or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the value directly to an `int`, you should first check its contents:

```
value = input ("Enter temp:  or q to quit ")
if value == 'q':
    return

value = int(value)
```